# How do format exports of multiple modules in NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have the following code in my db.js file:

```
const mysql2 = require('mysql2/promise');

// Connect to server (locally for development mode) ----- NEW VERSIN
const pool = mysql2.createPool({
    host     : "ENDPOINT",
    user     : "admin",
    password : "PASSWORD",
    port     : "3306",
    database : "DATABASE",
    waitForConnections: true,
    connectionLimit: 10,
    queueLimit: 0
});

module.exports = pool;
```

And in my app.js file I have:

```
const pool = require('./db');

async function checkUser(username) {
  const result = await pool.query('SELECT * from users WHERE username = ?', [username]);
  if (result[0].length < 1) {
    throw new Error('Row with this username was not found');
  }
  return result[0][0];
}

async function check() {
  let user = await checkUser("username");
  console.log(user);
}
```

check();
But I'm getting the error:

```
(node:42037) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: pool.query is not a function
```

This is weird, because when I run all the code in the db.js file it works fine, so I'm probably messed up the export/require bit of it, please help!

**ANSWER: HOW TO EXPORT MULTIPLE FUNCTIONS**

In the document you are exporting, write as follows:

```
  module.exports = {FunctionName1, FunctionName2, FunctionName3};
```

In the document you are importing to, write the following:

```
const {FunctionName1, FunctionName2, FunctionName3} = require('./whereyouareimportingfrom');
```

Comment: I try your same code on my computer, and it's working for me.
Are you sure that file `.db.js` is in the same directory of `app.js`?
Can you try to log in the console the `pool` variable for check that is right file

Comment: I'm actually running it in passport.js that is in the same directory, yes. When I console.log(pool) passport in db.js I get "object object" and for (pool.query) I get the query function. When I console.log(pool) in passport.js (the other file) I get the first function in my OP above - i.e. the async function that is used to connect to the server, and console.log(pool.query) I get undefined..... really don't understand this.

Comment: Btw - I have another database function that is my old one, I export them together like: "module.exports = connectDB, pool;" - maybe that's where the problem is? EDIT: Yes it seems to be working now, I made the exports the wrong way, I deleted the old one and just exported "pool" and that solved it. Thanks for helping me come to that conclusion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had done the exports the wrong way, I tried exporting two functions by doing: "module.exports = ConnectDb, pool;" And that didn't work. When I removed the first function and only exported "pool" it worked.